# Would installing a desktop environment slow down a server?

Tags: centos, gnome, performance, desktop-environment

I would like to install Gnome Desktop with CentOS7 and see how it works. Can Gnome be turned on and off when rebooting, or easily removed if needed?

Comment: Apparently, by changing a line in `/etc/inittab` you can turn GDM on and off ( http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-uninstall-gdm-centos-fedora-redhat-linux/ )

Answer (score 3):

Installing it... no. Running it at the same time, making the desktop environment and the other application compete for resources (CPU time, memory, IO, etc.), then the answer is yes. The more applications you have running competing for resources, any or both of them will slow down.

Answer (score 2):

Just having GDM running (i.e., when no desktop session is started) shouldn't have much of an impact. It will eat some memory, which will eventually be swapped off if needed, but I doubt it will have an impact on CPU or disk I/O when idle. You might also run a lighter DM or none at all.

But yes, it can be turned on and off as needed, in which case it will have no impact at all. You can just disable the GDM/lightdm/whateverdm service.

Alternatively, in Redhat and family, usually runlevels 3 and 5 are equivalent, with [runlevel 5 booting to a GUI and runlevel 3 to no GUI](http://blog.zloether.com/2009/07/disable-gui-in-centosrhel.html). So if your server runs on runlevel 3, it shouldn't autostart X.

Answer (score 1):

Having it installed does not really slow it down. It does use some memory and diskspace though.
However, what are you planning to do with it? running a browser would slow down your server. When there are no active programs in the desktop environment it doesn't have a noticeable impact.
I used to install a desktop environment for some clients so their sysadmin could run some system-checks (or start some update) just by point & click every once in a while. But for daily use I would avoid installing it.

It is very easy to remove, or just edit /etc/inittab :

```
id:5:initdefault:
```

change it to use runlevel 3:

```
id:3:initdefault:
```

(it will start without gui)